# Pylance in VS Code reports undefined variable with import *

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Using VSCode v1.61.0
I have a python package, a single folder named "tfmodules" with a whole lotta modules, and in the init.py I'm doing this:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

In my code I import it like so:

```
from tfmodules import *
```

Then I call the modules with something like this:

```
def write(aci_topology_model, provider_source, provider_version):
    with open('fabric-bringup.tf', 'w') as f:
        x = fabricbringup.tf_write_fabric_bringup(aci_topology_model, provider_source, provider_version)
        f.write(x)
```

fabricbringup is a module in the package.
The code works just fine, but Pylance is throwing 36 reportUndefinedVariable instances, one for each module called.

The specific error (from one of the modules) is:

```
"fabricbringup" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)
```

I have selected the proper interpreter for the venv in vs code, and I tried adding this to the settings.json file:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["tfmodules", "/home/aj/projects/python/dcnet-aci-lld-convert/tfmodules"]
```

But I still get the errors from Pylance. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the full error messages in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you will not be adding any extensions at runtime how about creating a file that will generate all references directly to "__init__.py"?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
    import glob
    modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
    print(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
    __all__ = ["\t\"" +basename(f)[:-3]+"\",\n" for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py') and not f.endswith('__add__manager.py')]

    f = open(join(dirname(__file__), "__init__.py"), "a")
    f.write("__all__ = [\n")
    f.writelines(__all__)
    f.write("]\n")
    f.close()
```

Result will look something like this:

```py
#(previous contents of __init__.py)

__all__ = [
    "file1",
    "file2",
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I spent a little time this weekend consolidating the modules. It made more sense structurally to add more classes and keep fewer modules. So then it was relatively easy to add the modules manually to all. After that the Pylance errors went away. I guess the Pylance extension just doesn't support dynamically-generated all